# Why do I lose <textarea> content when going Back?

Tags: networking, gmail, safari

I run Gmail in "Basic HTML" mode and sometimes lose composed email because the network has disappeared for various reasons when I'm trying to send the message. To recreate:

1. Switch Gmail to "Basic HTML" mode
2. Compose an email
3. Turn off Wi-Fi (or unplug Ethernet)
4. Send the message

Result: Safari will show a blank page saying you've got no network, and when you try to go "Back" after regaining network, the message is gone.

I thought modern browsers retained user input in `<textarea>` fields when going back and forth in tab history.

I'd to know where to turn to solve this problem. Is this a bug in Safari/WebKit? Is it a bug in how Gmail is implemented? I'd like a technical explanation of why this is happening.

**EDIT: Safari does indeed preserve form fields without using JavaScript or server-side tricks. So why does this fail with Gmail?**

```
a.html:
<form action="b.html" method="post">
<textarea placeholder="Write some text here"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="Then click here"/>
</form>

b.html:
<p>Now go back</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Modern (sic) browser retain the data in a form when reloading it using JavaScript or similar features which are apparently not in the "Basic HTML" which you selected.  That is not necessarily a limitation of the *browser* but of the technology which was used.

Further reading:

- [How to reload current page without losing any form data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17591447/how-to-reload-current-page-without-losing-any-form-data)
- [HTML - input value kept after Refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1799899/html-input-value-kept-after-refresh)
- [Keep form data when going back](https://www.webmasterworld.com/html/4219283.htm)

Comment: Please see my edit.